# How to store resume details in MySql database

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am developing a website (using PHP,MySQL) that deals with resumes of job-seekers. So the database should hold data like education details, projects, skills, etc. I have created different tables for them like shown below.

**Basic info table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `candidates` (
  `candId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `firstName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lastName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `contact` char(10) NOT NULL,
  `address` text NOT NULL,
  `gender` char(1) NOT NULL,
)
```

**Experience table**

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `Experience` (
  `candId` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `companyName` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `duration` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `jobRole` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `workType` varchar(50) NOT NULL
)
```

Like this,i have created tables for master degree(course,percentage),bachelors degree(course,percentage),skills(name,efficiency),achievements,etc.

In a page,i want to display all the information.For that 10 tables should be accessed in the page.I know that will load the page slowly.Are there any better ways to implement it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is use [indexes](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-indexes.html), [foreign keys](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html) and [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/join.html) to achieve the performance.

So Table which have **candId** should be referenced from main **candidates** table using foreign keys.

Now when you fetch candidates's all details, use single query using **JOIN** to get all the candidate's related data. 
This will help you to improve performance issue.

Comment: So , The only thing is all the data should be fetched at a time using JOIN. There is no problem with database design, right?